# Envio de Formulario AJAX + PHP

Tags: php, ajax, formularios

Estoy tratando de armar un codigo de ingreso de user y pass....
Una vez que valida que el usuario existe en la base de datos, quiero q se redireccione a la pagina de inicio ..

El problema que tengo es que despues del boton "Enviar" no hace nada! ( La llamada a la base y la consulta la hace... pero no me recarga la pagina al HOME)..

Esta es la invocacion al ajax una vez ingreso los datos de login:

```
function submitForm_ingresar(){
        var usuario = $("#usuario").val();
        var password = $("#Contrasena").val();

 $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "ingreso_verificacion.php",
           data: { usuario: usuario , password: password },
           success : function(result){window.location.href("home.php");}
       }); 
    }
```

Luego esto invoca a ingreso_verificacion.php donde hago la verificacion:

```
<?php     
session_start();           

// Conexion a la base 
$bd_host = "xxxx";
$bd_usuario = "xxxx";
$bd_password = "xxxx";
$bd_base = "xxxx";

$link = mysqli_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password);

mysqli_select_db($link,$bd_base);

$usuario = $_GET["usuario"];
$password = $_GET["password"];


                $accion = "Select * from usuarios where usuario = '".$usuario."' ;";
                $consulta = mysqli_query($link,$accion); $registros = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

                if ($registros <>0){
                           // extraigo el password del usuario
                           while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $consulta ) )   
                                    {$pass_tabla= $r['password'];}   

                           // comparo si coinciden
                               if($password == $pass_tabla )  

                                  {$_SESSION['admin'] = $_GET['usuario'];
                                   print("Usuario Correcto");}

                               else {print("Usuario Incorrecto");}
                }

?>
```

Hasta aca me funciona todo perfecto!!
Pero no se como redireccionar a home.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiar **window.location.href** por [window.location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

Quedando de la siguente manera:

```
function(result){window.location.replace("home.php");}
```

Answer (score 0):

La redirección esta mal escrita. Deberia ser la siguiente

```
function(result){ window.location.href = "home.php"; }
```

Comment: de hecho eres tu quien lo escribió mal, revisa la sintaxis de una función

Comment: Revisa la domentación de la **location** , te dejo unos links de apoyo 

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: ya corregiste pero lo que tenias mal era una llave faltante, nada que ver con la info de los links

Comment: bueno eso si lo estaba mal culpa de copy&paste jejeje